# Start a background process on Qt and load responsive shell environment

Tags: qt

I am playing around with Qt to create a simple GUI for some more advanced analysis with the software called OpenFOAM. Right now, I want to start an application of the toolbox OpenFOAM using`QProcess::execute`. It is working but for the application I need to load the environment in the shell.

Commonly, if I work in the terminal I first do have to source the environment file that loads all libraries and solvers one can use. However, in Qt, I am not aware how to achieve that.

Example. In the terminal I need to do the following:

```
    source /path/to/environementFile
    simpleFoam > logFile   << application
```

I want to start the application `simpleFoam` in the background of my GUI after clicking on a button. Right now, I do have the following:

```
    QProcess::execute(QString("/home/shorty/OpenFOAM/platforms/bin/simpleFoam"));
```

This works but the shared library that are needed by the application are not loaded (missing source of the environment file). Is there a way how to process more commands within one execution call?

Comment: See [`QProcess::setProcessEnvironment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment).

Comment: Seems to work if I modify my $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable here. However, I want to source a file that automatically sources the corresponding data. Still not able to get it work.